# DIMACS Examples with few variables

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am currently working on an SAT Solver using quantum computing. However, since current quantum computers are limited to a few qubits, I am in need of examples ranging from 4-30 variables. I know of a webpage that has DIMACS Files for 50+ variables but not less. Anyone know how to find ones with lesser variables?